# ¿Cómo quitar un evento a un elemento del html o mejor dicho hacer que una función se deje de ejecutar? javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Resulta que con jquery yo especifiqué que al darle click a un botón, este le suma a una variable y ejecuta una condicional la cual divide el número de la variable entre 2 y comprueba si el resultado es igual a 0, entonces ejecuta una función en la cual ordeno que al darle click a un elemento haga cierta acción.

El problema reside en que no sé cómo hacer para detener dicha función  en el caso que la condicional no se cumpla y tire el `else` (ya que estoy haciendo un botón de editar los campos de unos `divs`, y entonces cuando le doy click a dicho botón me debe de dar la opción de editar los distintos campos y cuando le doy de nuevo al botón, ya esa opción no me debe aparecer)

```
<tr id="cuerpo-tabla">
    *este es el campo que quiero editar*
    <td class="estatus">
        <div class="registro">
            <p class="tabla">registro</p>
        </div>
    </td>

    *este es el boton para editar*
    <td><i class="fas fa-edit editar"></i></td>
</tr>
```

```
var click = 1;
$('#cuerpo-tabla').click(function(){
    click++;

    if((click%2) == 0) {
        *selecciono el elemento y ejecuto la función mandándole como parámetro el elemento, para que la función al detecta que yo hago click en dicho evento ejecute otras acciones*
        var registro = $(this).parent().siblings('td').children('.registro').children('p');
        editarRegistro(registro);
    } else {
        *lo intenté de esta manera seleccionando el elemento y tratando de remover dicho evento pero no funciona*
        var etiqueta = document.querySelector('.registro p');
        etiqueta.removeEventListener('click', editarRegistro);
    }
});
```

Comment: no se mucho pero que tal si pones una variable boleana en el if y lugo la cambies a false para que no se cicle.. no se mucho pero tal vez funcione.. suerte..

Comment: Es posible que esto te interese: https://api.jquery.com/off/

Answer (score 1):

hay un evento especial para los doble clicks (si lo que querías era ejecutar esa función solo en un doble click). Para usarlo tienes que escribir `'dblclick'` a la hora de agregar el **addEventListener** y listo.

Por otro lado si lo que quieres es que específicamente cuando se den 2 clicks (sin importar el tiempo intermedio) se ejecute tal función y mientras eso no pase no se ejecute, lo que te aconsejo es que intentes con un condicional (tal vez usando la idea del comentario anterior) en la que si tu condición es **true** se ejecute y si no, pues simplemente no. O tal vez puedes ser más creativo y en el caso de ser **false** mostrar una señal al usuario o no sé. creo que solo bastaría con algo como lo siguiente:

```
if(variable === true){

// Aquí puedes ejecutar una función con todo lo que quieres hacer o escribes el proceso directamente. Como quieras
  function()
}

// y en el caso de que la condición sea false simplemente la función no se ejecuta
```

Eso es todo lo que te puedo decir porque estoy empezando en este lenguaje. Suerte.